# Mongoose and GraphQL queries

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, graphql

Here I have a mongoose Schema

```
name : String,
class : String,
skills : [{ skill_name : String }]
```

How I do make it on GraphQL inputs ? so I can save them to mongodb

Like

```
input Students{
 name :String!
  class :String!
skills : "how to do it in here"?
}
```

Comment: You do : `[skill]`, `skill` should also be a type.

Comment: it says, ``the type of Students.skills must be input Type but got. [skill]`` and I am also already make the ``type skill{ skill_name : String }`` and I've also tried ``input skill { skill_name : String }`` but when I run this query and return name and it's skills ``mutation { addStudents(input students : { name : "test", class : "A" , skills : { skill_name : "punching" } } ) { name skills } }`` it says ``string cannot represent value : { skill_name : "punching" }`` right when I return the skills and like so, I am doing it wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make GraphQL schema of input Student like this

```
input Students{
  name: String!
  class: String!
  skills: [String!]!
}
```

However, don't treat GraphQL schema and Mongoose schema the same. One is used for communicating client <-> server, other is used for server <-> database